# REST API/JSON - Querying Oracle IDCS users

Tags: rest

Ok folks, I have some basic understanding of REST API/JSON and how to query data from a REST API endpoint. I know every endpoint is different, particularly attribute names and query parameters and things of that nature. In my case, though I'm working with Oracle IDCS as the REST endpoint and I'm using postman as the REST client to fetch data. Trying to get users lastlogindate within a specified date range. Not sure how to build the query. I would also like to query only users that are a member of particular group. I can at least get lastsuccessfullogindate of all the users but not able to filter on a specific date range (say users who have not logged in between Jan 1, 2023 and April 1, 2023).  Any help will be highly appreciated.

I can at least get lastsuccessfullogindate of all the users but not able to filter on a specific date range (say users who have not logged in between Jan 1, 2023 and April 1, 2023).